# Get Session ID on Login

Tags: php

I have script with a session login system. After user log, i store User ID, name and level.

```
 if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
 $_SESSION['user_id'] = $result['user_id'];
 $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result['user_name'];
 $_SESSION['user_level'] = $result['user_level'];    
 // Redirect
 header("Location: dashboard.php"); exit;
```

Now, I need to have a second script installation  on same server

SCRIPTA

SCRIPTB

If user log in SCRIPTA and change URL to SCRIPTB, i'ts able to login o B installation.

A way to solve this problem is add a unique ID to each session.

But how to forward and check ID between pages?

Comment: I don't understand, why don't you just use the session?!

Comment: No I mean the session. Or the session Id yeah, whatever. I just don't see what your use case is.. What are you actually doing?

Comment: Actually on protect page i check user level only. Maybe i need to add sessionID and check this one with Cookie?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You may want to have another `SESSION` variable, to define all of the above.  For example, if you are trying to sort Accounts by the user_id, then set a session variable `$_SESSION['account']`.  Then, have a page to redirect based upon that id.

Comment: for this purpose you would need to use $_COOKIE[]; as  $_SESSION[]; is only usable on the page witch it is created on.

Comment: you may wont to try 
<?
 if (!isset($_SESSION)) 
 {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $result['user_id'];
  $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result['user_name'];
  $_SESSION['user_level'] = $result['user_level']; 
 }
 // Redirect
 header("Location: dashboard.php?user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."&user_name=".$_SESSION['user_name']."&user_level".$_SESSION['user_level']); exit;
 ?>

Answer (score 0):

You may wont to try

```
  if (!isset($_SESSION)) 
 {
     session_start();
     $_SESSION['user_id'] = $result['user_id'];
     $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result['user_name'];
     $_SESSION['user_level'] = $result['user_level']; 
 }
```

- create a new php file with the above in it.
- include this file in every page that requires the session data.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with Sable Foste suggestion.

I have added a column with a unique ID for user and check this one when page is loaded.

Query DB:

```
// Verify hash
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user_hash FROM users WHERE user_id =".$_SESSION['user_id']);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
$user_hash = $row['user_hash'];
```

Compare hash:

```
if ($_SESSION['user_hash'] != $user_hash) {
    header("Location: index.php?error=1"); exit;
}
```